# Evaluation Order of Operands

Tags: c, operator-precedence, order-of-execution

What will be the output of the following program in C?I am basically confused whether main() will call t1() or t2() first.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a=40;
int t1()
{
    int a=20;
    return a;
}
int t2()
{
    int a=30;
    return a;
}
int main()
{
    int k=t1() + t2();
    printf("%d",k);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it have not decided which one is called first. Which is the same with the tip in this case.

Comment: Did you intend to change the global variable a in your functions?

Comment: nah not exactly i was trying to figure out what would be the evaluation order of the function calls i.e. t1()+t2(),is the order of evaluation undefined??What if there r three functions i.e. t1()+t2()+t3(),what would be the order of evaluation in this case?

Answer (score 4):

Since all the functions return the values of local variables, your code is identical to this:

```
int a = 40;

int t1() { return 20; }
int t2() { return 30; }

int main() { printf("%d", t1() + t2()); }
```

Or, even simpler:

```
int a = 40;
int main() { printf("%d", 20 + 30); }
```

Or simpler yet:

```
int a = 40;
int main() { fputs("50", stdout); }
```

In the first version, it is both unspecified and irrelevant which function call subexpression is evaluated first.